# Can I be sure that this will always returning a unique alphanumeric string?

Tags: javascript, unique

I'm trying to generic a universally unique alphanumeric string in javascript. I've tried to use UUID but the format isn't desirable. Currently I am doing the following:

`Math.floor((Math.random() * Date.now())).toString(16).toUpperCase()`

This results in a string like: `4198A8BEA4`. This is the desired format and relative length.

Can I be sure that this will always return a unique alphanumeric string?

If so, how can I be sure?

Comment: You cannot be sure.

Comment: It is possible a random number and a moment in time to generate the same string.....

Comment: Can you explain why? @Pointy

Comment: It may be *highly unlikely* that the current timestamp and the value returned by the `.random()` function produce a product that repeats a previous product, but it is not impossible.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to achieve the desired result as mentioned above? @Pointy

Comment: Side note: The whole point of using a UUID is that statistically speaking, the probability of generating the same UUID twice _is_ really zero.  For 10 char string, the probability of duplication is much higher (albeit still rather low).

Comment: The closest you can get to truly reliable is to use some value returned from a service that is guaranteed (to the greatest extent possible) to be a monotonically increasing value, or else a cryptographically-secure random value with a *lot* of bits, like 128 at least.

Comment: And `Math.random()` is not a cryptographically-secure random number source.

Comment: A service with a robust international time synchronization implementation (like NTP) that *never goes backwards* and which can produce high-resolution millisecond (or better) timestamps would be a good start towards something pretty reliable, though even that depends on site traffic load.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, the resulting string will probably have 10 or 11 characters, and the characters will vary from 1 to F, so there are 16 ** 10 = 1099511627776 possibilities.

The likelihood of a collision is *low* - it'll probably be good enough for most code - but it's not zero.

To guarantee no collisions, the easiest way would be to use numeric indicies instead, and increment each time a new one is needed.

```js
let i = 0;
const getNextUnique = () => i++;

console.log(getNextUnique());
console.log(getNextUnique());
```

The index is easy to see in the result, though. If that's a problem for you, use a [one-way hash function without collisions](http://www.crypto-it.net/eng/theory/one-way-function.html#:%7E:text=A%20one%2Dway%20hash%20function,properties%20as%20one%2Dway%20functions.) on it. (though, even cryptographic hash functions can have collisions, [depending on the algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1))

SHA-256 does not have any known collisions, and such a collision is considered [near impossible under current circumstances](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/52602), so you [could use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63499899) if you wanted:

```js
let i = 0;
const getNextUnique = async () =>
  Array.prototype.map
    .call(
      new Uint8Array(
        await crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-256", new TextEncoder().encode(i++))
      ),
      (x) => ("0" + x.toString(16)).slice(-2)
    )
    .join("");

(async () => {
  console.log(await getNextUnique());
  console.log(await getNextUnique());
})();
```

Comment: ...or just use the full 16 byte UUID, which also practically has no chance of a collision.